Cannot record audio on iOS Safari browser
I'm using MediaRecorder to record audio and sending it to the backend as a blob but I'm facing issue with iOS Safari browser where I'm getting blob of length 0 at the backend. Same code was tested on older iPhone (iOS 15.5) and everything works fine there, problem seems to be with iOS version 17.4 and above. Facing same issue with chrome as well on iOS.
Below is the code that converts chucks into blob:
async readFile(chunks, type = "audio/wav", filename = "abc") {
    const name = `${filename}.${type.split("/")[1]}`;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const modifiedFile = new File(chunks, name, {
        type: type,
      });
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(modifiedFile);
      fileReader.onloadend = () => {
        resolve(fileReader.result);
      };
      fileReader.onerror = () => {
        reject(fileReader.error);
      };
    });
  }


According to Webkit, I highly doubt that it works with .wav files. Webkit/Apple states that "Safari currently supports the MP4 file format with H.264 as video codec and AAC as audio codec" when using the MediaEncoder API.
